# Add Google Ads custom variable to the existing Pixel via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, tagging

I've created a Google Ads custom variable `client_id` and would like to add it to the existing Pixel that is set up on the website via GTM. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to do it via Google Tag Manager. There're [instructions](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9962082?hl=en#zippy=%2Cduplicate-variables%2Cconversion-adjustments%2Cconversion-tracking-using-tags-on-your-website) on how to
do it by adding a custom variable to an event snippet on the website, but there's no information regarding its setup via GTM.

Does anyone know how to add a Google Ads custom variable to the existing Pixel via GTM? Also, this variable needs to be dynamic as it should pick up different values.

Here's how the existing Google Ads tag looks:
[image]

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the screenshot about how you use GTM to install Google ads?

Comment: Hi @Darrellwan! I've attached the screenshot for the current Google Ads tag setup. Let me know if it's sufficient. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't see there are settings about custom variables in this tag. The suggestion here is you can test about change the tag to customHtml and paste the code contains **gtag()**.

Comment: When adding a custom HTML tag, should I input only gtag() there? Something like the following snippet? `gtag('event', ‘conversion’, {'send_to':
'TAG_ID/AW-CONVERSION_LABEL',
‘client_id: 'example_string'
});` Or should I also add Google tag (gtag.js) to custom HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Ads Remarketing tag instead of the standard conversion tag, technically they fulfill the same function, however the remarketing tag presents the custom variable options. Remember to put the conversion label in that tag and also the same trigger, just like you would put it in a conversion tag.